# C++ selective print of cerr stream by module names

Tags: c++, debugging

Suppose we have a 30 K lines code database in 20 modules : that is for each *.cpp and *.h file for each. During development process the source code was decorated with local variables look up through cerr. Sometimes it has advantages duing the same with gdb, sometimes not.
One would like to keep the cerr stream clean /silent , and be able to pick up only writes to cerr from modules he wishes. How do I :

1) Distinguish the writes to cerr , that they contain info on from which module they do come from ? 
2) Add cmd line options for build binary, which would specify which modules are allowed to write to cerr ( the ones I wanna see  ) .

Comment: I recommend you start looking for some logging framework, instead of building your own. The most common seem to be log4cxx, log4cpp and log4cplus. Use Google to look for them and check which might fit you best.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: In fact the best way to do this is to use a logging framework (as per Joachim Pileborg's comment). The below only really applies if you absolutely must hang onto the code that you alraedy have, but want to neaten it up.

The best way to do this would be with the pre-processor, using `#ifdef` directives to select the code to build.

For example

```
#ifdef CERR_DEBUG_BUILD_MODULE_1
cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "\tCERR DEBUG OUTPUT" << endl;
#endif
```

That statement might be even better wrapped in a small macro:

```
#ifdef CERR_DEBUG_BUILD_MODULE_1
#define LOG( x ) cerrLogPrint( x, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#else
#define LOG( x )
#endif
```

where

```
void cerrLogPrint( const char* const log, const char* filename, unsigned int line)
{
     //PRINT
}
```

Comment: Well to ask more :D I would ask whether http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/ can facilitate  it request logging up to specified compilation unit at runtime I know there is the formatting option, which has the filename, but I would have to regrep the output , slowing the performance and doing a lot of unnesesery login requests. Thing is I hesitate between Denis's snippet-like or larger framework. It seems that teh feature I want has to be implemneted by myslef, whatever solution I do choose.

Comment: It depends on what you want out of this in the long term. Investing in a logging framework will help you learn it and will make the project more flexible for future logging changes. However if you want a quick and simple way to log with the file name (you can use __FUNCTION__ as well) then the above may be what you want. Up to you.